# C# console app that does Excel Interop - failing when running as scheduled Task -System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, excel, interop, scheduled-tasks

As the title states, I have a C# console app which uses interop to open Excel and create a new workbook. The code works fine when running the console app via command line. However this exception is thrown when running the console app via a scheduled task:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component   with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005
```

It is thrown from the following call:

```
_xlApp = new Excel.Application()
```

The scheduled task is setup to use my credentials (I am an administrator). Based on other forums I have made sure I have granted full control to my account at Component Services --> Computers --> My Computer --> DCom Config --> Microsoft Excel Application, but no luck.

I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. Not sure what the next step should be, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a windows service to call out to a library containing the Excel generation code. That fixed the error. However there was another COM exception when calling the workbook.Save() method. No matter what I tried that error would not go away. I read another post which stated that this was a security precaution and therefore by design.

However, calling workbook.***SaveAs()*** will produce the same result and works fine when called from a windows service.

Thanks for the input funkymushroom. Hopefully this post will be helpful to someone else struggling with Excel Interop automation.

Answer (score 2):

The error [80070005](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm) is a **COM Access Denied** error.
Are you sure that your credentials have the ability to instantiate the Interop Library?
Check this [link](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070005.htm)  and follow some of the debug steps.
(*I know you said you did the DCOMConfig thing already, but there are more test scenarios in this link and hopefully something here will help you*)

Comment: I tried all the steps under the local security policies and dcom configuration, the same error is still thrown

Comment: I have permission to instantiate the Interop Library. I have run this app successfully via command line/explorer. It only fails under the scheduled task

Comment: Does the scheduled task run as a different user?

Comment: No it runs as my account. I am the admin of the box

Comment: I am not sure then, you might want to run it as a service.
see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890 for running a command line tool as a service. That might be an alternate approach.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. With the above method, would you control timing for when the command line tool was run? The idea with the scheduled task is that I could set it to run at a certain time on a weekly basis. If there is not a way to get this to work as a scheduled task then it would seem that the better plan would be to encapsulate the console app's logic into a library and call out to it from a windows service that I could write from the ground up and control the timing of the code execution.  But I don't want to go that route if this can be made to work as a scheduled task.

Comment: With a service, its less about the timing and more about establishing if the service could be run under your credentials.
You could schedule this service to start at a certain time every week (although this is very hacky/inelegant).

I hear you on not wanting to go the latter route, that would take a bunch of time, and add extra risk to it.

Have you tried writing a powershell script or a vbs to instantiate the Excel interop?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, I have resolved the issue by performing the following steps.

**DCOM Configuration**

1. Click Start -> Run
2. Enter DCOMCNFG and press OK. This will open the DCOMCNFG window.
3. Browse down the tree to Console Root -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer
4. right-click on "My Computer" and select properties
5. Select the "Default Properties" tab

   - Enable Distributed COM on this computer - Option is checked
   - Default Authentication Level - Set to Connect
   - Default Impersonation Level - Set to Identify
6. Select the "COM Security" tab
7. Click on Access Permissions ' Edit Default
   a. Add "Anonymous", "Everyone", "Interactive", "Network", "System" with Local and Remote access permissions set.
8. Click on Launch and Activation Permissions ' Edit Default
   a. Add "Anonymous", "Everyone", "Interactive", "Network", "System" with Local and Remote access permissions set.
9. Click on OK
10. Close the DCOMCNFG window

Later I got an exception while opening the Excel. So please make sure that the following paths are available on the server.

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft

This might help guys like me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem - it turned out that on the scheduled task I needed to tick the box "Run with highest privileges" on the General tab of the task set-up.  This resolved the problem - it was so simple!  Hope it helps someone else too.